# Slow log in times when not connected to domain

Tags: windows-7, login

I am having the same slow boot isue as in your post and I was wondering if you ever found a solution?
Corrently my only solutoin is to disconnect all network connections until the machine boots and then turn on the network connections.  I don't like this solution and was wondering if a better one was ever found?

Thank you,
Brian

Comment: Who are you talking to Brian?

Comment: Dear Brian, thank you for your letter. We have no idea what post you're referring to. Please provide details as to your exact problem. Say hello to your Mother for us. Sincerely, SF.

Comment: yes a better solution would be to run atari's GEM operating system that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A domain machine will always look for its domain during log in if it has a network connection.  This is by design and unavoidable.